# Is it Possible to Share a Local Picture and Caption Using the Facebook Android API?

Tags: android, facebook

I've been trying to implement a feature in my app which would allow a user to share an image and give it a caption on Facebook. This image is stored on the device while the Facebook Share Dialog requires a URL for pictures. In iOS this is incredibly simple while on Android after hours of searching I have still yet to find any solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks,

Evan

Answer (score 0):

How to upload photos are documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos/ and there is also documentation on how to set a description. But be aware that the description the user have to type every single character. You can't add anything to it

Comment: Is this publishing to the user's photos on the wall or just sharing the picture with a caption so that it can link to something else?

Comment: That publish to the user's photo and the user can set a caption. You can never choose the caption. Only the user can type it in